# I am unable to save ajax data into a variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I hava ajax call and I am getting the data back correctly. But i am unable to assign data to local variable. I am trying to assign data to item_price. I am getting data as 100.00 OR 115.25

Here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
              type: "get",
              url: "index.php?module=product&view=price",
              data: { code: v },
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data) {
                    item_price = data;
                }

            });
```

---

Thank you Guys, async: false, worked for me.

Comment: I'm guessing `dataType: "script"` is wrong.

Comment: You're not able to use `item_price` in your success function?

Comment: Alert the data before assining to item_price.

Comment: @Jonathan M Thank you! Yes, I am unable to assign in success any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var item_price;
$.ajax({
          type: "get",
          async: false, //If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false
          url: "index.php?module=product&view=price",
          data: { code: v },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
                item_price = data;
            }

        });
```

Comment: Yes async: false, worded Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
              type: "get",
              url: "index.php?module=product&view=price",
              data: { code: v },
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data) { //console.log(data);/*get your price index and assign*/
                    item_price = data.your_price_index;
                }

            });
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I am new to javascript. Sorry but what is price_index here?

Comment: The index of the price in the array you are encoding from the `php` side

Comment: If you can edit your question with the index.php and the function product..i can help you more

Comment: I am not encoding array. just echoing price only ie 100.00 or 115.25

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('index.php', { module: product, view: price, code: v }, function(data)
{
    var item_price;
    item_price = data;
});

otherwise try this

$.post('index.php', { module: product, view: price, code: v }, function(data)
{
        $("#My_Div").html(data);
});
```